Replacing Glyph and MultiGlyph in Fontforge
I am fairly new in designing a font in Fontforge (or, in any other environment). What I am trying to achieve is to digitise one font (Bengali). Because Bengali language has compound characters in it, I preferred downloading Noto Bengali Font and replace each glyph there. Now I am facing the following problems:    
 

Keeping the Anchors Intact: I believe the anchors are for defining the shape when vowel modifier (ক + আ = কা) or compound characters (ন + ন = ন্ন or আ + ঁ = আঁ). So I don't like to disturb the anchors for a simple character. But while removing the strokes from the base character and paste the SVG of the new font, it becomes challenging to keep the anchors intact as removing stroke from the base character also remove the anchor.

Multiple Appearance : In Bengali, most compound characters may have more than one appearance. E.g. (ক + ত = ক্ত / ). This kind of variations have been achieved in LaTeX for example in while writing calligraphic letters in there are two fontfaces for D using mathcal and pazocal. Is it called Ligature? How to define that in FontForge?

AutoMerge Compound Glyph: For compound characters the constituent glyphs look different from the basic one. How to define new font face automatically in FontForge?


